# unexpected output trying to generate an ordered linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to write a program that generate an ordered random linked list.
The problem is that the output sometimes is only 4 numbers and sometimes is an 
infinite sequence of numbers. I think the problem is in the `gen` function, how can i fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 5

struct node{
    int v;
    struct node *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct node Node;
typedef Node *NodePtr;

void gen(NodePtr *startPtr);
void print(NodePtr start);

int main()
{
    NodePtr startPtr;
    startPtr = NULL;
    gen(&startPtr);
    print(startPtr);
    return 0;
}

void gen(NodePtr *startPtr)
{
    NodePtr currPtr, lastPtr, newPtr;
    int r;
    lastPtr = NULL;
    srand(time(NULL));


    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        currPtr = *startPtr;
        r = rand()%101;
        while(currPtr != NULL && r > currPtr->v){
            lastPtr = currPtr;
            currPtr = currPtr->nextPtr;
        }
        newPtr = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        newPtr->v = r;
        newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
        if(lastPtr == NULL){
            *startPtr = newPtr;
        }
        else{
            lastPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
            newPtr->nextPtr = currPtr;
        }
    }
}

void print(NodePtr start)
{
    while(start != NULL){
        printf("%d ", start->v);
        start = start->nextPtr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lastPtr` must be initialized to null in the `for`-loop.

Consider `&& r > currPtr->v` being false on a 2nd (3rd...) iteration of the `for` loop. Consider that on a previous iteration the `while` loop was executed one or more times, so `lastPtr` has a value.

Then on this iteration where `&& r > currPtr->v` is false the old value of `lastPtr` is used in the `else` part where it should have been null.

So:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        lastPtr = NULL;
        currPtr = *startPtr;
```

...and then I ran it in the debugger and found also:

```
    newPtr = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newPtr->v = r;
    newPtr->nextPtr = currPtr;     // set it here
    if(lastPtr == NULL){
        *startPtr = newPtr;        // because here it is needed too
    }
    else{
        lastPtr->nextPtr = newPtr; // and no lomger needed here
    }
```

The case I found was when `rand()` returned zero and the new node had to be inserted at the front.

Comment: Ok, now works better but there Is still a problem, sometimes It not generate the correct number of random value("N")

Comment: Yes thanks. But why the first node can not just be NULL? It should not point to anything

Comment: @Alex, think what happens when you insert a node at the front: `currPtr` is the old `*startPtr`. Becasue the `while` loop has not executed, `lastPtr` is still null and so `*starPtr= newPtr` is executed. But the old `*startPtr` will be lost if you don't assign it as `newPtr->nextPtr `.

Comment: I still not understand. If the while loop is not executed currPtr = NULL. So newPtr->nextPtr = NULL should be the same as newPtr->nextPtr = currPtr.

Comment: If the while loop has not executed then `currPtr = *startPtr;` and this may not be null if there is an element in the list. If `r` is smaller than the first element it must be inserted at the front.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

1. When `lastPtr == NULL`, you forgot to set `newPtr->nextPtr` to `currPtr`. You need to set `newPtr->nextPtr = currPtr` unconditionally.
2. The `lastPtr` variable needs to be reinitialized to `NULL` each time around the loop.

Original code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        currPtr = *startPtr;
        r = rand()%101;
        while(currPtr != NULL && r > currPtr->v){
            lastPtr = currPtr;
            currPtr = currPtr->nextPtr;
        }
        newPtr = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        newPtr->v = r;
        newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
        if(lastPtr == NULL){
            *startPtr = newPtr;
        }
        else{
            lastPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
            newPtr->nextPtr = currPtr;
        }
    }
```

New code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        currPtr = *startPtr;
        lastPtr = NULL; // <-- (re-)initialize lastPtr
        r = rand()%101;
        while(currPtr != NULL && r > currPtr->v){
            lastPtr = currPtr;
            currPtr = currPtr->nextPtr;
        }
        newPtr = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        newPtr->v = r;
        if(lastPtr == NULL){
            *startPtr = newPtr;
        }
        else{
            lastPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
        }
        newPtr->nextPtr = currPtr; // <<-- set newPtr->nextPtr unconditionally
    }
```

A more robust solution should also check the result of `malloc`.

Comment: I've reinitialized `lastPtr` in the loop. Try it now, it works for me!

Comment: @PaulOgilvie It didn't properly insert the new node when inserting at the beginning of the list, as you found out in your answer! I think we came up with the full solution between us. :)

Comment: Ian, yes, we have :-)

Answer (score -1):

Your code is uselessly complex. Instead of traversing the list at every iteration, use an head and tail pointer. If sorting is required, the value array can be initially sorted.

```
int comp( const void* a, const void* b)
{
     int a_int = * ( (int*) a );
     int b_int = * ( (int*) b );   
     if ( a_int == b_int ) return 0;
     else if ( a_int < b_int ) return -1;
     else return 1;
}

void gen(NodePtr *startPtr)
{
    NodePtr head, tail;
    int a[N] ;
    for(int i = 1; i < N; i++)
      a[i]=rand()%101;
    qsort(a,N,sizeof(N),comp);

    int i=0;
    // first node
    head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    head->nextPtr=NULL;
    head->v=a[i];
    tail=head;        
    for(i = 1; i < N; i++){
      tail->nextPtr= malloc(sizeof(Node));
      tail=tail->nextPtr;
      tail->v=a[i];
      tail->nextPtr=NULL;
    }
    *startPtr=head;
}
```

Comment: Your code does not insert the new node in a sorted fashion, which is what he wants.

Comment: Right, I missed that.

Comment: Ok but It should be ordered.

Comment: Updated the answer with an initial sort. That's somehow cheating, but for a large number of values, it should much more efficient.